# How to create a huge .png in Java joining smaller .pngs?

Tags: java, image, out-of-memory, png

I have a lot of small .png in a folder, and I want to join them together, the problem is that the final Buffered image is too big, resulting in an OutOfMemoryException (bigger than 32k x 32k);

Is there a way to create that image without having to inizialize a huge BufferedImage, but just, like, loading one small .png at a time, and appending it to another image on the disk, and so on, until the image is done?

If not, how to deal with this?

Comment: Show your code. Or look at JVM startup flags (`-Xmx`),

Comment: Consider [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and [im4java wrapper library](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) to call ImageMagick functions from java.

Comment: Being clever and pairing the images, merging 2 at a time, and then 2 products of the first round and so on... have a look at this answer to help you with step 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922276/how-to-combine-multiple-pngs-into-one-big-png-file

Comment: @diginoise that's how I'm actually dealing with this, the problem is that my final BufferedImage is too big.

Comment: how much memory do you give this process?

Comment: With 6GB of allocated memory I'm able to create a 32000x32000 .png image, but the point is that I want a "generic" way to deal with this (Creating an image as big as I want), where, "ideally", the only limit will be my disk memory.

Comment: Perhaps PNG-specific operations will help like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6176487/798021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [PNGJ](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj), which lets you read and write PNG images line by line.

In [Snippets](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/wiki/Snippets) there is an example (Image tiling) that puts together several images of the same size.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!