# image created in scala does not look as expected. not sure why

Tags: scala, canvas, png

i start by creating a 2d array all with a value of 2. then setting a few values from the bottom right of the array to 5

```
var map = Array.fill(5, 10)(2);
map(4)(9) = 5
map(3)(9) = 5
map(4)(8) = 5
map(3)(8) = 5
```

this array will be represented by an image. each number 2 should be a blue square. the rest should just be white

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.io._
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.awt.{Graphics2D,Color,Font,BasicStroke}
import java.awt.geom._

object DRAWPROB {
 def draw(map : Array[Array[Int]]){

        val size = (30 * (map(0).length-1), 30 * (map.length-1))
        val canvas = new BufferedImage(size._1, size._2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
        val g = canvas.createGraphics()
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE)
        g.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth, canvas.getHeight)
        g.setRenderingHint(java.awt.RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,java.awt.RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)
        var d = 0;
            for(d <- 0 to map.length-1){
                  var e = 0;
                  for(e <- 0 to map(0).length-1){
                  g.setColor(Color.BLUE)


                    if(map(d)(e) == 2){ g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(d*30.0, e*30.0, 30.0, 30.0));} // ill find a way to do this once i can load the image
                    else {println("not at "+ d + " " + e)}
                                                                                    }
                                                                    }
g.dispose()
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(canvas, "png", new java.io.File("island_drawing.png"))
}
```

it just makes 1 large blue square but i wanted a section missing from the bottom right

[expectation vs reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UityX.png)

why am i getting this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine multiple PNGs into one big PNG file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922276/how-to-combine-multiple-pngs-into-one-big-png-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue with this code part: `new Rectangle2D.Double(d*30.0, e*30.0...` - the first argument is `x` coordinate so it should be multiplied on `map` column value, rather on row , and same with second argument `e*30` which is `y` so it should by multiplied on `map` row value.

I've refactored your code for better understanding, at least for myself, so please take a look as an example:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.awt.{Color, Rectangle, RenderingHints}

import javax.imageio.ImageIO

import scala.reflect.ClassTag

/**
 * Immutable table model, possibly empty inside
 */
class Table[T](underlying: Array[Array[T]]) {
  def columnsCount: Int = underlying.headOption.map(_.length).getOrElse(0)
  def rowsCount: Int = underlying.length

  def rows: Seq[Int] = underlying.indices
  def columns: Seq[Int] = underlying.headOption.map(_.indices).getOrElse(Nil)

  def apply(row: Int, column: Int): Option[T] = {
    val rowExists = row < rowsCount && row >= 0
    val columnExists = column < columnsCount && column >= 0
    if(rowExists && columnExists) Some(underlying(row)(column)) else None
  }

  def update(row: Int, column: Int, value: T): Table[T] = {
    val copy = underlying.clone()
    copy(row)(column) = value
    new Table[T](copy)
  }

  def foreach[U](f: ((Int, Int, T)) => U): Unit = {
    val rowColumnValue = for {
      row <- rows
      column <- columns
      value <- apply(row, column)
    } yield (row, column, value)

    rowColumnValue.foreach[U](f)
  }

  override def toString: String = underlying.map(_.mkString(",")).mkString("\n")
}

object Table {
  def apply[T: ClassTag](rows: Int, columns: Int, initValue: T): Table[T] = {
    new Table[T](Array.fill(rows, columns)(initValue))
  }
}

class Draw(cellSize: Int) {

  def draw(table: Table[Int]) {
    val width = cellSize * table.columnsCount
    val height = cellSize * table.rowsCount

    val canvas = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
    val graphics = canvas.createGraphics()
    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE)
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth, canvas.getHeight)
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)

    table.foreach { case (row, column, value) =>
      if (value == 2) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE)
        // This is main fix part
        val x = column * cellSize
        val y = row * cellSize
        graphics.fill(new Rectangle(x, y, cellSize, cellSize))
      }
    }

    graphics.dispose()
    ImageIO.write(canvas, "png", new java.io.File("island_drawing.png"))
  }
}


object DrawApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val draw = new Draw(30)
    val table = Table(5, 10, 2)
      .update(4 ,9, 5)
      .update(4, 8, 5)
      .update(3, 9, 5)
      .update(3, 8, 5)
    println(table)

    draw.draw(table)
  }
}
```

This produced expected image. Hope this helps!