# Is it possible to Autosave a webpage as an image inside of R?

Tags: r, autosave, autorun

I think this can be done but I do not know if the functionality exists.  I have searched the internet ans stack high and low and can not find anything.  I'd like to save www.espn.com as an image to a certain folder on my computer at a certain time of day.  Is this possible?  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762162/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-screen-shot-of-a-given-web-site and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986820/converting-webpage-into-image-using-javascript/12986864#12986864  Possibly running these ideas with `system`

Answer (score 1):

Selenium allows you to do this. See http://johndharrison.github.io/RSelenium/ . DISCLAIMER I am the author of the RSelenium package. The image can be exported as a base64 encoded png. As an example:

```
# RSelenium::startServer() # start a selenium server if required
require(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://espn.go.com/")
# remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE) # to display image
tmp <- paste0(tempdir(), "/tmpScreenShot.png")
base64png <- remDr$screenshot()
writeBin(base64Decode(base64png, "raw"), tmp)
```

The png will be saved to the file given at `tmp`.

A basic vignette on operation can be viewed at [RSelenium basics](http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/12843) and 
[RSelenium: Testing Shiny apps](http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/13408)